# Burning DVD is taking too long

Tags: dvd, brasero

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I used to burn my DVDs with Brasero Disc burner without any problem until a month ago. But recently the process is taking too long than normal. The process proceeds as normal but in the end, it gets stuck with `finalizing` message and nothing happens. **I can't even eject my DVD drive after the `finalizing` message**. The DVD drive is able to read the DVDs normally; only writing new DVDs is a problem (copying to/from flash drives has no problem).

Comment: Are you using the same type of DVD media as before, and how long since you last successfully burned a DVD? The drives do go bad after a while as well.

Comment: Does it happen while copying files to a flash drive or a pen drive too?

Comment: @Jobin No, it doesn't happen while copying files to pen drive.

Answer (score 0):

open Brasero Go to edit --> Plugings --> **untick** to **image checksum**

[image]

Also select **Direct Burning** it ask when your files ready to Burn

[image]

[image]

Now You Can Burn Fast